# criar servlet com modo doGet

Tags: java, servlet

Vocês podem me ajudar a fazer esse exercício? eu preciso criar um modo `doGet` e depois criar outro arquivo para ser a saída do meu servlet o problema e que não tenho ideia de como faço essa junção entre os dois... segue o código

```
package br.com.servlets;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


    public class ServletName extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7475043552851895502L;


    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

        char primeiroNome = request.getParameter('primeiro').value;
        char segundoNome = request.getParameter('segundo').value;

        var resultado = primeiroNome + " " + segundoNome;

        if(primeiroNome == "" || segundoNome == ""){
                alert("os campos devem ser preenchidos!");
        }else{
            alert(resultado);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Como assim "criar outro arquivo" você está se referindo a resposta da requisição get ?

Comment: isso mesmo amigo.